# XCode: Rearrange Output/Main Window

Tags: xcode, nib, xib

Is it possible to move the output/find window that sits above the source editor to the bottom?

I was hoping there might be a hidden preference some where, or perhaps someone has edited the nib file to do the re-arrangement.

cheers

Comment: You could always make a suggestion on bugtracker…

Answer (score 1):

No.  Apart from the three "layouts" in Xcode > Preferences > General there is no customization of the UI layout in Xcode.  The top level layout is not done with nibs, so a hacked nib will not do it.